# React Native MainActivity.java createApplicationDelegate() how to merge two necessary methods

Tags: java, react-native, android-activity

in a recent [upgrade to react native 0.71.3](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.67.2&to=0.71.3#RnDiffApp-android-app-src-main-java-com-rndiffapp-MainActivity.java) part of the upgrade is to add a method:

```
@Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
        );
  }
```

the instructions are to add this to `MainActivity.java`. This is all well and good but there is a problem :

our code already had this method yet in an entirely different form, which uses a completely different mechanic

```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
  return new InitialPropsReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
        return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
```

I need to merge the functionality and return a `ReactActivityDelegate` with everything we need. Has anyone got experience of how to do this properly? It has me stumped.

Answer (score 5):

I think this does it actually

```
@Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
    ) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
        return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      };
    };
  }
```